# learn permutation of string vb net

Tags: vb.net

i got an array of char and want to create a permutation with special condition

for example if i input 2, then it will generate permutation of 2 character
the char array contains 6 elements like this `inChars = {c,f,a,b,m,p)`

when i run it with

3 character input, it generates, permutation of `f,a,b`

4 character --> `f,a,b,m`

**my 1st question** is why it begin from 2nd element of array (f) instead of (c)

**and my 2nd questions** how to create something like this: when i input 3 character, it will generate 2 and 3 subset of char instead of only 3 subset, it will be like

`c,f`

`c-a`

`....`

`c,f,a`

`c,a,m`

`.....`

here's the screenshot

[image]

here's the code

```
Public Class permute
Dim ItemUsed() As Boolean
Dim pno As Long, pString As String
Dim inChars() As Char = {"c", "f", "a", "b", "m", "p"}

Private Sub permute_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load  
End Sub

Sub Permute(ByVal K As Long)
    ReDim ItemUsed(K)
    pno = 0
    Permutate(K, 1)
    tb.Text = K
End Sub

Private Sub Permutate(ByVal K As Long, ByVal pLevel As Long)
    Dim i As Long, Perm As String
    Perm = pString

    For i = 1 To K
        If Not ItemUsed(i) Then
            If pLevel = 1 Then
                pString = inChars(i)
            Else
                pString += inChars(i)
            End If
            If pLevel = K Then
                pno = pno + 1
                Results.Text += _
                pno & " " & " = " & " " & pString & vbCrLf
                Exit Sub
            End If

            ItemUsed(i) = True
            Permutate(K, pLevel + 1)
            ItemUsed(i) = False
            pString = Perm
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Permute(tb.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub tb_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tb.TextChanged
    If tb.Text = "" Then
        Results.Text = ""
    Else
        Permute(tb.Text)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: OK, but where is the code? It's hard to tell what's wrong when you don't show the code...

Comment: sorry i forgot i've updated the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `For` loop to start from `0` to `K-1`:

```
For i = 0 To K - 1
```

**Update** - *second question*

```
Sub Permute(ByVal K As Long)
    results = New List(Of String)
    ReDim ItemUsed(K)
    pno = 0

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To K
        Permutate(i, 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thx @MarcinJuraszek it worked. if i may ask again, how to generate 2 & 3 subset if the input is 3. then 2,3,4 subset if the input is 4 and so on?

Comment: I've updated my answer. The easiest way is just call `Permutate` multiple times with `K` from `2` to your length.