# Link numbers with an equation/algorithm

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, visual-studio-2012, math, anagram

I am making an anagram solver in Visual Basic that gives you every possible combination when you enter a string. I need to work out how many combinations there are depending on the amount of characters in the string and how many different characters there are.

> E.G.
>
> Sample string:
>
> abc
>
> Total characters: 3, Different Characters: 3
>
> Possible combinations: 6
>
> abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba

I need an equation (using the number of characters and different characters) to link this to a string that contains a different amount of characters.
I've been using trial and error to try and figure is out, but I can't quite get my head around it. So far I have:

> ((letters - 1) ^ (different letters - 1)) + (letters - 1)

which works for a few different letter counts but now for all.

Help please???

Comment: possible duplicate of [learn permutation of string vb net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077405/learn-permutation-of-string-vb-net)

Comment: I don't really understand what the permutation is doing and how it relates to my issue

Comment: ah, I sort of understand what he's doing but I don't see how it actually works...

Comment: what you are asking for is called a permutation.  he starts with a char array, you start with a string, but you now know a string is basically a char array, so the connection should be simple

Comment: I sort of understand it, but the way he formatted it with no commentary and strange variable names I just can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll lead you to the answer, but I'll try to explain along the way.  Let's say you had 10 different letters.  You'd have 10 choices for the first, 9 for the second, 8 for the third, etc.  Ultimately, there would be 10*9*8*7*6...*2*1 = 10! possibilities.  However, sometimes you'll have multiple instances of the same letter.  For example, using that for the string "aaabcd" would overcount possibilities, because it counts each of the a's as distinct letters, even though they're not.  To correct for that, you would have to divide by the factorial of the number of repeated letters.  A good way to calculate the total number of possibilities would be (total number of letters factorial)/ (product of the factorials of the number of repeated instances of each letter).

For example: 
There are 6!/(3!) ways to arrange the letters in "aaabcd"  
There are 6! ways to arrange the letters is "abcdef" 
There are 6!/(3!*2!) ways to arrange the letters in "aaabbc" 
There are 10!/(5!*3!*2!) ways to arrange the letters in "aaaaabbbcc"

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For the possible counting number, it's exactly the same as computing [Multinomial Coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)

A simple explanation is that, for no repeating characters, 
It's simply permutation = `n!`
(It is easy to understand if you draw a tree diagram, with first character has `n` choices, second character has `n-1`choices...etc.)

However as you may have repeating characters, you will double count many of them.

Let's see an simple example: for `aaa`, how many possible arrangements **IF WE COUNT EVEN THE OUTCOME IS THE SAME**? 
Answer is `3!`(aaa,aaa,aaa,aaa,aaa,aaa)

This gives us an idea that, when we have a character appearing for `m` times, we will count `m!` instead of `1`

So the counting is just `n!`(all possible arrangements, including same outcome) / `m!` (a character appear for m times)
 Same for more characters repeating:  `n!/a!b!c!..` (first character appear `a` times, another appear for `b` times...)

If you understand the concept behind, then you will find that, actually for those "non-repeating" characters, it's just dividing an `1!`. For eg, character (multi)set = `{a,a,a,b,b,c}`, #a = 3, #b = 2, #c = 1, so the answer (without repeating count) is `(3+2+1)!/3!2!1!` and fraction of this format is named multinomial coefficient as stated above.

In programming point of view, you can just pre-compute all factorials (with a pretty small `n` though as `n~30` is already too large for a variable to store) with simple for loop

```
declare frac = array(n); 
frac[0] = 1;
FOR i=1; i<=n;i++
    frac[i] = i*frac[i-1]
```

For a larger `n`, you may just calculate `double/float` division on the fly in the loop to avoid overflow..you may face precision problem though.

If you further need to output the different strings,  you may use `DFS` to backtrack all the possible outcomes. Or if you could use another language like C++, you can use built-in function like `next_permutation()` after sort the character set.

Comment: Oh sorry to miss one part...if you are interested, there is a simple but clever proof of "why a binomial / multinomial coefficient must be an integer" : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158/division-of-factorials/2192#2192

See Bill's answer in this link.